# DataTables warning: table id=data-table - Ajax error

Tags: html, json, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am getting `table id=data-table error`. I have even converted my text file to `json` file with parse command. Any ideas what is causing this. I have tried to search every where for this issue.

Please help.

My Text File

```
{
    "Orders": [
        {
            "Address": "124, KAPADIA INDUSTRIAL",
            "Dabba Type": "LUNCH AND DINNER",
            "Email": "jamesbond@gmail.com",
            "End date": "29/4/2017",
            "Phone number": "9619582277",
            "Session": "VEG",
            "Start date": "15/3/2017",
            "User id": "CaXXchcC3XhAifuk7P4YprzSGqB3",
            "Username": "james bond"
        },
        ...Still more data is there below
    ]
}
```

Script file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        "ajax" : {
            "dataType" : 'json',
            "contentType" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "type" : "POST",
            "url" : "data/mumbaidabbawala.txt",
            "dataSrc" : function (json) {
                return $.parseJSON(Orders);
            }
        },
        "columns" : [
            { "Orders" : "Address"},
            { "Orders" : "Dabba Type"},
            { "Orders" : "Email"},
            { "Orders" : "End Date"},
            { "Orders" : "Phone number"},
            { "Orders" : "Session"},
            { "Orders" : "Start date"},
            { "Orders" : "User id"},
            { "Orders" : "Username"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: There is an unnecessary comma in your json file (line 13). Also, it should be `return $.parseJSON(json.Orders);` in your script file, line 9.

Comment: I added return $.parseJSON(json.Orders); but i am still getting ajax error

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Open your browser console and in the Network Tab see the response, there you have more detail. Also you can rigth click and open in new windows to see it.